# Use of GORM methods in Integration test

Tags: grails, integration-testing, grails-orm, spock

I'm trying to use gorm find method on my domain class, inside of an Spock Integration Spec.

My code:

```
class myDomainClassSpec extends IntegrationSpec{
    ...
    def 'my test'() {
        when: ...
        then:
            MyDomainClass.find { id == 1 }
    }
    ...
}
```

This fails, throwing:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: id for class: grails.gorm.DetachedCriteria
```

If instead I code: MyDomainClass.findAll().find { id == 1 } it works.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly how Spock works here, but it looks like you `MyDomainClass.find` call is creating a [DetachedCriteria](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#detachedCriteria), What I would try to get around this is either do

```
MyDomainClass.findById(1)
```

or if you are using a more complicated criteria try either

```
MyDomainClass.where { id == 1 }
```

or just using a [Criteria](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#criteria)

```
(MyDomainClass.createCriteria()) { id == 1 }
```

Comment: I forget to mention that gorms .find method works in my application, it only fails when called from a test (when it's not inside a method)